# Toolstrip Drop Down Button Not Large Enough

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

Well the answers from stackoverflow looked promising, but no luck yet. Also, I may not have quite enough experience yet to see it.

Simple I thought: I am looking for a larger drop down arrow in a ToolStripDropDownButton as an item in the collection. The tool strip drop down button is very small. I would like it to be 3 times the current size. Slightly larger would be of benefit as well. The drop down, when selected, reveals a menu of items.

Is it possible to use the ToolStripRenderer or a user control to get this as desired (unless there is a property I do not see) or ?? I am not that familiar with custom controls in a Winforms environment, so any help with snippets or direction would be helpful. In other words, wondering, if a user control is needed, what do I need to make it work for this scenario? That said, I am looking for any solution that will work. Thanks for any help/ideas!!!!

Comment: This is a very unusual request, which usually means it is an XY Problem.  You realize that it is only a visual hint and you don't actually have to click the arrow to get the dropdown?  There's a wholelotta button you can click.

Comment: Hi Hans and thanks for the good comment. The button is so small though. It begs to be bigger (my opinion and then independently stated from testing). Also, knowing that you can click in the entire button can require a user mental dereference (see the arrow and translate to being able to hit button not just the arrow). Thanks again. You make a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your own Renderer and override the OnRenderArrow method:

```
public class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
  protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e) {    
    if (e.Item.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripDropDownButton)) {
      Rectangle r = e.ArrowRectangle;
      List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
      points.Add(new Point(r.Left - 2, r.Height / 2 - 3));
      points.Add(new Point(r.Right + 2, r.Height / 2 - 3));
      points.Add(new Point(r.Left + (r.Width / 2),
                           r.Height / 2 + 3));
      e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
      e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, points.ToArray());
    } else {
      base.OnRenderArrow(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Then apply it to the ToolStrip:

```
toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
```

You may have to change the button's AutoSize property to false and set the width of the button yourself to get the proper space.

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect! Thank you. I had a software crisis come up. I will check this weekend and mark as solution. Thanks again. This looks fantastic!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the button by setting the `AutoSize` property to false and then setting the `Size` property to what you need.  As far as making the arrow bigger, I don't think you can do that, but at least it will make the button bigger.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This could help someone with the button.